# C++ returning pointers value not changeable

Tags: c++

I have run into a strange problem. When i try to write a function that returns a pointer to a subclass which i swap for a different instance of that subclass i get the "error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value" error.

Tthe problems is at the `one->getMe() = two;` line :

```
class subClass{};

class someClass{

public:

subClass * pointer;

someClass(){
    pointer = new subClass;
}

subClass * getMe(){
    return pointer;
}

};

int main(){

someClass * one = new someClass;
subClass * two = new subClass;

one->getMe() = two; 
}
```

I'm a bit new to c++ so the problem might be horrible simple. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to modify - the value of `pointer` or the value of the object pointed to by `pointer`?

Comment: the name `getMe()` suggests it can _get_ a value, not _set_ the value

Comment: You are returning a rvalue. Use a set method to set a new pointer.

Comment: The object pointed to by pointer, swap it with another element.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a function instead of simply using the publicly accessible member variable? i.e. `one->pointer = two`

Comment: This was just some example code, in the real project they are private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
one->getMe() = two;
```

Is trying to assign the pointer at two to one->getMe(). But one->getMe() returns a temporary copy which you cannot assign to. If you want to return the pointer by reference and thus be able to change it then you can use the signature

```
subClass *& getMe();
```

as others have suggested.

That being said, you're exposing the inner workings of a class for all and sundry to see and modify, in particular pointers to objects on the heap which may or may not be deallocated correctly which is unwise.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response, solved the problem. I'm using it in a more safe environment in the real project.

Answer (score 5):

The pointer that you return from the function is a copy of the pointer in the object.  It is a temporary, you cannot assign to it.  Even if you could assign to it, it would do no good, because it is no longer connected to the pointer in your object.  If you want to be able to assign to the object's pointer after returning it from the function, you want to return the pointer by reference.

```
subClass *& getMe() {
    return pointer;
}
```

You should also may want to consider adding a const overload in order to work on const objects.  It might look like this:

```
subclass * const & getme() const {
    return pointer;
}
```

Comment: It's sad that the only answer that considered const-correctness ends up being least voted. +1